# How to create a buffer using CH3COOH and CH3COONa that has a pH of exactly 3.75?

Tags: acid-base

> I need to create a buffer using $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and $\ce{CH3COONa}$ that has a pH of exactly $3.75$.
>
> A $\pu{50 mL}$ sample of your buffered solution will have to be able to withstand the addition of $\pu{25.0 mL}$ of $\pu{0.100 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ solution.
>
> The buffered solution will break after the addition of no more than $\pu{35.0 mL}$ of the $\pu{0.10 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$.

Here is what I have so far:

$$\mathrm{pH}= 3.75 \implies [\ce{H+}] = \pu{10^{-3.75} M} = \pu{1.78 \times 10^-4 M}$$

\begin{align}
\ce{NaCH3COO &-> Na+ + CH3COO-}  &&\text{(common ion effect)}\\
\ce{CH3COOH &<=> H+ + CH3COO-}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{a} &=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{CH3COO-}]} {[\ce{CH3COOH}]}\\
1.8\times{10^{-5}} &=\frac{(1.78\times{10^{-4}})[\ce{CH3COO-}]} { [\ce{CH3COOH}]}\\
\frac{[\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]} &=\frac{(1.8\times{10^{-5}})}{(1.78\times{10^{-4}})}\\
\frac{[\ce{CH3COO-}]}{[\ce{CH3COOH}]} &= 0.1011 : 1~\text{(ratio)}
\end{align}

I found the ratio of $[\ce{NaCH3COO-}]$ to $[\ce{CH3COOH}]$, but I don't know what to do from here.

EDIT: "Break": The point where there's no acid left and the solution stops acting as a buffer. "Withstand": meaning that there can be a $\mathrm{pH}$ change of at most $1.0$. Thanks, guys!

Comment: The "withstand" requirement is not quantified. The "break" I understand as all acid is spent.

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. 

Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation? If you are not, this may help  https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/acid-base-equilibrium/buffer-solutions/v/buffer-solution-calculations

Comment: Can you give us the whole problem exactly as it was stated to you? Then give us your thoughts on how to solve it.

Comment: Equally, look up *buffer capacity* (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution#Buffer_capacity).

Comment: "withstand" and "break" are not precise terms. How much tolerance for pH are we talking about here? A change of pH of no more than 0.1 unit? Perhaps your instructor has defined these terms quantitatively.

Comment: Added NaOH reacts with acetic acid, shifting acid/acetate ratio and therefore pH. At some point there is no acid left and solution stops acting as a buffer. This I consider a breaking point.  The meaning of "withstand" is unclear, unless it is meant some maximal oH change.

Comment: @iad22agp has raised the salient points. I know of no quantitative definition for the terms "withstand" and "break". Any solution will have to somehow define those terms exactly.

Comment: @MaxW I have merged the two posts now, you can put a custom flog on such posts, too.

Comment: @Poutnik I clarified the words "break" and "withstand" above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cathy The requirements is not possible to meet, as they are mutually contradictory. The buffer cannot have as big and and the same time as low capacity as required. The difference of the spent volumes of $\ce{NaOH}$ is too small. If usage of acetate buffer was not mandatory, it would be achievable with buffers with pKa near 3.75 and not 4.75 as for acetic acid. In such a case, the buffer capacity would be decreasing and not increasing between these pH values and the final break would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, there is considered $$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=4.75$$ and therefore $\mathrm{pH}=3.75$ was chosen for easy calculation, as:

$$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}+ \log \frac {c_{\ce{A-}}}{c_{\ce{HA}}}$$

and therefore
$\frac {c_{\ce{A-}}}{c_{\ce{HA}}}=0.1$

For the buffer change to $\mathrm{pH}=4.75$, at least $\pu{25 ml 0.1 M NaOH}$ has to be spent. ("withstand")

$$\frac {c_{ws,\ce{A-}}}{c_{ws,\ce{HA}}}=1$$

Calculating molar amounts to be equal for both acetic acid and acetate:
$$0.1\cdot c_{\ce{HA}}\cdot V_\mathrm{buf}+c_\mathrm{NaOH}\cdot V_\mathrm{NaOH}\\=c_{\ce{HA}}\cdot V_\mathrm{buf}-c_\mathrm{NaOH}\cdot V_\mathrm{NaOH}$$

From that, we calculate minimal concentration of acetic acid in buffer:

$$2\cdot c_\mathrm{NaOH}\cdot V_\mathrm{NaOH}=0.9\cdot c_{\ce{HA}}\cdot V_\mathrm{buf}$$

$$c_{\ce{HA}}=\frac{2\cdot c_\mathrm{NaOH}\cdot V_\mathrm{NaOH}}{0.9\cdot  V_\mathrm{buf}}=\frac{2\cdot 0.1\cdot 0.025}{0.9\cdot  0.05}=0.005/0.045=1/9 \mathrm{~ mol/l}$$

$$c_{\ce{HA},min}=\frac19 \mathrm{~ mol/l}$$
$$c_{\ce{A-},min}=0.1 \cdot \frac19=\frac1{90} \mathrm{~ mol/l}$$

All acetic acid in $\pu{50 mL}$ of the buffer must react with not more than  $35~\text{ml}$ of $0.1~\mathrm{M~}\ce{NaOH}$.

$$\begin{align}
n_{\ce{NaOH}}&\lt 3.5\mathrm{~mmol}\\
n_{\ce{CH3COOH}}&\lt 3.5\mathrm{~mmol}\\
n_{\ce{CH3COONa}}&\lt 0.35\mathrm{~mmol}\\
\end{align}$$

As the latter 2 amounts have to be present in $\pu{50 mL}$ of the buffer:

$$\begin{align}
c_{\ce{CH3COOH}}&\lt \pu{70 mmol/L}\\
c_{\ce{CH3COONa}}&\lt \pu{7 mmol/L}\\
\end{align}$$

Summary:
Concentration of acetic acid in the buffer must be at least $\frac19=0.1111\pu{ mol/L}$ and not more then $\pu{0.07 mol/L}$.

**Such requirements is impossible to meet and such a buffer is not possible to prepare.**

By other words, the buffer cannot have at the same time so big buffer ("withstand") capacity and so low "break" capacity.

If usage of acetate buffer was not mandatory, the goal would be achievable with buffers with pKa closer to 3.75 than the acetic acid has.  In such a case, the buffer capacity would be decreasing and not increasing between these pH values and the final break would be faster.

Comment: See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/116186/35806, where the suitable approach is elaborated in larger details.